# How is defined the 2-norm of a random vector?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normed-spaces

How is defined the 2-norm of a random vector $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

What is the vector is composed by i.i.d. random variables $X_1,...,X_n\in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

You make the vector from random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ by putting them as the coordinates of the vector, e.g. $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$. The 2-norm of this vector is then just $\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \ldots + X_n^2}$.